# is facebook connect or facebook login available for WAP/mobile site

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-login, wap

I want to implement fb connect and fb login functionality on my mobile site.

Is facebook connect or facebook login available for WAP/mobile site?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the server side i.e. PHP SDK because javascript won't be supported on wap sites.

Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/